# Constructing phrase with "During"

Tags: translation

Grammatically speaking, is it correct if I translate

> During my two years stay in Japan, I have visited many places.

to

> 日本に住んでいた二年で、色々な所へ行きました

？

Answer (score 3):

Your translation looks already correct and natural. But I think it would be even better if you use the [kanji 間](http://jisho.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&keyword=%E9%96%93) and say like this:

- 日本に住んでいた二年【にねん】間【かん】で、色々な所へ行きました。
- 日本に住んでいた二年【にねん】の間【あいだ】に、色々な所へ行きました。